# How to challenge Hutter's algorithm?

Tags: complexity-theory

For a given sufficiently strong formal axiomatic system $\mathsf{F}$ (like $\mathsf{PA}$ or $\mathsf{ZFC}$) and any given function $p^*(x)$ that can be specified within the formal system $\mathsf{F}$, [Hutter's algorithm](http://www.hutter1.net/ai/pfastprg.htm) $M_{\mathsf{F},p^*}$ computes the function $p^*(x)$ nearly as quickly as any (provably quick) algorithm $p$ provably computing $p^*(x)$. More precisely

> Let $p$ be any algorithm, computing provably the same function as $p^∗$ with computation time provably bounded by the function $t_p(\xi)$ for all $\xi$. $time_{t_p}(x)$ is the time needed to compute the time bound $t_p(x)$. Then Hutter's algorithm $M_{\mathsf{F},p^∗}$ computes $p^∗(x)$ in time
>   $$time_{M_{\mathsf{F},p^∗}}(x) ≤ 5·t_p(x)+d_p·time_{t_p}(x)+c_p$$
>   with constants $c_p$ and $d_p$ depending on $p$ but not on $x$.

Here "provably" means that a proof can be found in $\mathsf{F}$. The algorithm could be interpreted as a generalization and improvement of Levin search, but I wonder whether it is always an improvement.

---

Can we use the formal system $F$ to construct a function $p^*$ for which Hutter's algorithm $M_{\mathsf{F},p^*}$ performs badly? How about asking whether a short proof of $\bot$ (i.e. a contradiction) can be found in $\mathsf{F}$? A short proof would be a proof with fewer than $n$ symbols, and we would use $x$ to encode $n$ in binary form. The function $p^*$ would just be a brute force search for the contradiction.

I think this should give a problem in $NEXP$, but the optimal algorithm to compute $p^*$ would have complexity $O(1)$, because the answer is always "no". But $M_{\mathsf{F},p^*}$ will take double exponential time in the length of $x$ to arrive at that conclusion, if I'm not mistaken. Now I wonder whether there are more interesting ways to make $M_{\mathsf{F},p^*}$ look bad, perhaps similar in spirit to Rice's theorem?

Answer (score 1):

> But $M_{\mathsf{F},p^*}$ will take double exponential time in the length of $x$ to arrive at that conclusion, if I'm not mistaken.

That $M_{\mathsf{F},p^*}$ will take double exponential time is a conjecture at best. Too see that this conjecture is pretty strong, take any formula $\phi$ that is formally independent of $\mathsf F$, and ask whether a short proof of $\phi$ can be found in $\mathsf F$. Any algorithm that can answer this question quickly (with "no") can also answer the same question for $\phi=\bot$ quickly (with "no"), because any formula can be derived in a single step from $\bot$.

> Now I wonder whether there are more interesting ways to make $M_{\mathsf{F},p^*}$ look bad, perhaps similar in spirit to Rice's theorem?

Formal systems are not just bad at proving their own consistency, they are also [famously bad at proving some sequence to be random](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~chaitin/sciamer.html). So we could ask whether a given finite sequence can be reproduced by some program shorter than $m$ symbols taking fewer than $n$ steps. The restriction to fewer than $n$ steps allows us to implement $p^*$ as a brute force search. If the sequence and $m$ are kept fixed and binary encoding is used for $n$, the resulting problem seems to be in $EXP$. Maybe it's better not to fix the sequence and $m$, because then the problem seems to be in $NEXP$.

What about a function $p^*$ based on Rice's theorem? No progress yet...

Answer (score 1):

We could do something similar to Squark's question [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/14587/7468):

Let $p^*$ be the program that takes an input $n$ and does the following:
"Run $M_{p^*}(n)$ for $n$ steps.
If it halted, output $|M_{p*}(n)| + 1$.
Otherwise output $0$."

Now $M_{p^*}(n)$ takes at least $n$ steps (proof by contradiction) but $M_{p^*}(n)$ can be computed by just printing $0$, which takes $1$ step.

However, in this argument we're implicitly assuming that the formal system Hutter Search uses is consistent.
The system itself can't assume that, so it doesn't find the 'proof' that  $M_{p^*}(n) = 0$ for all $n$.